# Does Teleporting free you from restraining chains?

Tags: dnd-4e, conditions, teleportation

Me and my group are wondering: If someone who can teleport is being held in chains, can he teleport away? Do the chains around him teleport with him, or do they fall to the ground and the character is free?

Comment: I’m talking about what could happen in many situation. If you’re tied to a tree, chain in a dungeon.. something’s like that. I know that if someone grab you, you can still teleport. But what if you have handcuffs?

Comment: Both cases could be argued, it would really be up to the DM to make a ruling in that case. The rules are vague enough that the wording "teleports away from a physical restraint" could apply to chains in general, whether or not they are attached to anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Rules Compendium: pg 214

> **Immobilized or Restrained:** Being immobilized or restrained doesn't prevent a target from teleporting. If a target teleports away from a
>   physical restraint, a monster's grasp, or some other immobilizing
>   effect that is located in a specific space, the target is no longer
>   immobilized or restrained. Otherwise, the target teleports but is
>   still immobilized or restrained when it reaches the destination space.

So, if they are chained *to* something, they teleport free. If they are just tied up in chains, the chains teleport with them.